# Word/phrase to describe something bringing about a contrary result

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In this sentence, what could be added to say that the result was contrary to the person's intent/expectation?

> The meeting was planned to show that the board value employees’
> opinions, but (it) _______ .

Answer (score 9):

*backfired*:

> to have the reverse of the desired or expected effect
> *their plans backfired*
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backfire))

Answer (score 2):

> ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/counterproductive)) **counterproductive** adjective uk /ˌkaʊn.tə.prəˈdʌk.tɪv/ us /ˌkaʊn.t̬ɚ.prəˈdʌk.tɪv/
> having an effect that is opposite to the one intended or wanted:
>
> - Improved safety measures in cars can be counterproductive as they encourage people to drive faster.

- The meeting was planned to show that the board value employees’ opinions, but it was counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

*did a **U-turn**, perhaps?*

Per *Wiktionary*, the word means

> A reversal of policy; an about-face, a backflip.

*The government have done a U-turn and are now supporting greater European integration instead of opposing it.*

Answer (score 1):

You could modify *outcome* with an adjective like *suprise*; this is in fact the example given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outcome):

> **outcome:**
> something that follows as a result or consequence
> *a surprising outcome*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I made changes and hope the answer is now satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

***Go awry***:

> off the correct or expected course : AMISS
>
> - Their plans ***went awry***. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awry#:%7E:text=%3A%20off%20the%20correct%20or%20expected,Charles%20Dickens))